# Scrapy spider finishing early before all links have been checked

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using a Scrapy solution to scrape through a list of websites to find emails (based on https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-to-extract-contact-information-part-1-mailing-lists-854e8a8844d2). The spider runs as expected until about 30 seconds when it "finishes", however it has only crawled through about 25 of the near 5000 links I sent to it in start_urls. Here is the Spider:

```
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'email'

    def parse(self, response):
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_item) 

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return

        html_text = str(response.text)
        raw_mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)
        mail_list = []
        for email in raw_mail_list:
            if '.com' in email or '.org' in email or '.net' in email or '.co' in email:
                mail_list.append(email)

        dic = {'email': mail_list, 'link': str(response.url)}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
```

Here is what shows up in the debug log:

```
2020-05-31 04:15:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-31 04:15:13 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 8,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/builtins.ValueError': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 175382,
 'downloader/request_count': 475,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 475,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20920027,
 'downloader/response_count': 467,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 354,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 79,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 17,
 'downloader/response_status_count/303': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/406': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/503': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/999': 2,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 370,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 28.004682,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 8, 15, 13, 458883),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 10,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404': 2,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/406': 4,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/503': 2,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/999': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 473,
 'log_count/ERROR': 13,
 'log_count/INFO': 20,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 361,
 'retry/count': 9,
 'retry/max_reached': 4,
 'retry/reason_count/503 Service Unavailable': 4,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 475,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 475,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 475,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 475,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 8, 14, 45, 454201)}
2020-05-31 04:15:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you “send” links to `start_urls`?